# How to get text field disabled property

Tags: jquery

I have a div as shown below. How  to know if the location id is disabled or not ??

```
<div class="stTime fields">
    <input id="location" type="text" placeholder="Label (Example Office , Home) " disabled="">
</div>
```

I have tried this way

```
var prop = $("#location").prop();
```

but i am getting Uncaught TypeError: `Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined` in console

Comment: Any feedback for the answers below?

Answer (score 2):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u51c9h3t/2/)

```
var prop = $("#location").prop("disabled");
alert(prop)
```

Comment: You need to specify which property you want to check , here it is "disabled" .

Comment: @TusharRaj ,no  he just wrote `prop()` He didnt specify Which property like disabled.

Comment: Title: How to get text field **disabled** property

Comment: @Brian i mean  in CODE `var prop = $("#location").prop();`  , instead of this Specify the property in Code inside `prop()` .

Answer (score -1):

If you are using older versions of jQuery

```
  var prop = $("#location").attr('disabled');
```

As of `jQuery 1.6` , `.prop()` has been introduced

```
  var prop = $("#location").prop('disabled');
```

Comment: it depends which version of jQuery you are using

Comment: Check here http://jsfiddle.net/u51c9h3t/3/  It outputs disabled  . But it should output true or false ,which is given by `prop()`   got it ?

Comment: Again , if you have gone through jQuery `API` ,you should not have said this . jQuery `API` says that earlier versions (till 1.6) uses .`attr()` that returns `disabled` and after that `.prop()` got introduced that returns `boolean`.Got it ??

Comment: You shouldn't care about what worked 3-4 versions ago, use the latest

Comment: I have edited my answer to understand better .And people still used to work on the older versions . Talk about the projects that are existing from 10 years .